# Generate types from a parameter received in a function (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

everyone, first of all thanks for reading. Here is my problem. Let take this example

```js
// data
const data = {
  suggestion: {a: {nested: true}}
}

// Nested key types =>  suggestion, suggestion.a, suggestion.a.nested etc...
type NestedKey<S> = ......

// Return type the type of data
type Return<S> = (target?: NestedKey<S>) => S 

// function itself
function test<S>(data: S): Return<S>

const result = test(data)
```

Is there a way to make Return type like this,

```js
if user did not provide a target then result type is 'S' which is {suggestion: {a: {nested: boolean}}}

if user gives target as "suggestion" then result type is {a: {nested: boolean}}

if user gives target as "suggestion.a" then result type is {nested: boolean}

if user gives target as "suggestion.a.nested" then result type is typeof suggestion.a.nested, a boolean here
```

This the logic in plain js that i want to convert in typecsript.

Since

```js
console.log(data["suggestion.a"]) is not { nested: true } but undefined. But will be cool if it is
```

I need to split target, loop and provide the result

```js
function getType(data, target) {
    let result = data;
    // Assuming that k will always be correct and defined
    target && target.split(".").forEach(k => result = result[k])
    return result
}
```

I need some help to do that in typescript with data as generic type `S` and target as `NestedKey<S>`.

Thank you

Comment: You can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/wO2KEW) if you want; see the linked q/a for more information.

Comment: I am playing in the ground right now. Thank you